A kid from an african tribe teaches his dad how to be free
Can't remember this movie but I can remember some stuff about it;
It's about a kid, maybe from an African tribe, that teaches his dad how to be free. The kid is called "Meme-see-coo" which means cat piss, he moves with his dad to the city.
The kid is really good at firing spitballs out of a straw. He tells his dad he needs to learn to run breathing through his nose.

Where you watched the movie or TV show - England
When you watched the movie or TV show - Around 2k maybe 1990's
Any idea of how old it was - Around 2k maybe 1990's
Any idea of country of origin (if known) - American
Whether it was animated or not - Not animated


Sounds like Jungle 2 Jungle from 1997 starring Tim Allen (since you want the American version, but this is actually a remake of a French film called Little Indian, Big City from 1994).

A man learns he has a thirteen-year-old son who was raised in the jungle and brings the boy to New York City, turning his life upside down in the process.

The kid is called Mimi-Siku. He's Venezuelan, though. Here's the trailer:




Thank you, this has been bugging me for about 3 years only just got round to posting! Guess it was my incorrect spelling of his name! Again, thank you!
